# torch.max slower with GPU than with CPU when specifying dimension

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

```
t1_h = torch.tensor(np.arange(100000), dtype=torch.float32)
cuda0 = torch.device('cuda:0')
t1_d = torch.tensor(np.arange(100000), dtype=torch.float32, device = cuda0)
```

```
%timeit -n 10000 max_h = torch.max(t1_h, 0)
%timeit -n 10000 max_d = torch.max(t1_d, 0)
```

> 10000 loops, best of 3: 144 µs per loop
>
> 10000 loops, best of 3: 985 µs per loop

As you can see above, GPU takes much more time than CPU. But if I don't specify dimension for calculating max, then GPU is faster.

```
%timeit -n 10000 max_h = torch.max(t1_h)
%timeit -n 10000 max_d = torch.max(t1_d)
```

> 10000 loops, best of 3: 111 µs per loop
>
> 10000 loops, best of 3: 41.8 µs per loop

I also tried with `argmax` instead of `max` but it is working correctly (GPU faster than CPU).

```
%timeit -n 10000 cs_h = torch.argmax(t1_h, 0)
%timeit -n 10000 cs_d = torch.argmax(t1_d, 0)
```

> 10000 loops, best of 3: 108 µs per loop
>
> 10000 loops, best of 3: 18.1 µs per loop

Is there any reason why `torch.max` is slow on GPU after specifying dimension?

Comment: This seems to me like something that should be brought up as an issue on the pytorch issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered this myself, and [opened an issue in PyTorch](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/36900). It looks like it'll be fixed soon - maybe version 1.5 or 1.6? - but in the meantime the suggested workaround is to use

```py
ii=a.argmax(0)
maxval = a.gather(0, ii.unsqueeze(0)).squeeze(0)
```